# stuck in run unix v6 in my mac

Tags: unix, gcc

This is the first time I am trying to dive into unix kernel. So I think unix v6 will be a good beginning.
I found [this website](http://blogs.yahoo.co.jp/i_love_raspberry_pi/39244842.html) which helped me to install all the tool I needed, but I am stopped by a error while I was trying to "make" gcc.

Here is what I got:

```
In file included from ../../../libquadmath/quadmath-imp.h:24:0,
                 from ../../../libquadmath/math/acoshq.c:30:
/private/tmp/gcc-4.7.2/build/./gcc/include/stdint.h:4:25: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [math/acoshq.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-target-libquadmath] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tred again and again, and I really don't know what to do? I just want to start to learn unix v6, and these problems keep bothering me, so can anyone can help me out?

Comment: Ahhh I sense confusion... the page refers to something called xv6 which is *not* Unix v6! See [here](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2011/xv6.html)

Comment: i thought they are same.but no matter what it call,i really want it can work on my mac,so i can start to study it

Answer (score 0):

Unix v6 doesn't have `<stdint.h>` yet. That only came much later, with C99.

Actually, you might be better off to install [simh](http://simh.trailing-edge.com/) (or a [more current development version](https://github.com/simh/simh)) and a binary install of Unix v6. [Disk images](http://simh.trailing-edge.com/software.html) aren't too hard to find.

Comment: that error came along while i am trying to compile gcc,i am thinking to run unix v6 by qemu.

Comment: I don't think qemu runs PDP-11 code... for that you need simh (or one of a few other options). I'm not sure why you want to compile gcc, since you should have a C compiler on your system already, and gcc won't generate PDP-11 code either.

Comment: Oh, and the v6 disk image would have a compiler on board already, too. Hopefully there is no password for the root user, otherwise you have to get creative to get in :-) (Yes it is possible of course...)

Comment: i don't know why i have to compile gcc neither,i think the original gcc didn't have  I386-Jos-elf ,so have to compile it again

Comment: the reason i use qemu to run unxi v6,because i found a mit course which teach unixt v6(http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2011/schedule.html),i will try to work it on again,if it didn't work out,i will use simh

Comment: Well, anyway, since the question turns out to be about something else than suggested (it's not about Unix v6), I'm afraid I can't help you with this. Maybe you can edit the question to say that it is about xv6, which is inspired by Unix v6, and include some links to English references instead (like [this](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2011/xv6.html) or [this](http://left404.com/2012/01/30/installing-xv6-on-macos-x/))